# error: no 'operator++(int)' declared for postfix '++'

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Here the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/P5aP9a4bv):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int func()
{
    int i = 0;
    i++;

    return i;
}

int main() {
    auto foo = [sp=std::make_shared<int>(1)](){ int num = *sp++; return num;};  //no 'operator++(int)' declared for postfix '++' [-fpermissive]

    func(); //`i++` works well
}
```

Since it's legal to call `int i=0;i++;` and `*sp` returns the object of `int`, so I think `*sp++` is valid too.

Comment: You mean `(*sp)++`?

Comment: @MikeCAT  think so. `*sp++` is equivalent to `(*sp)++`. Anything wrong?

Comment: `*sp++` is not equivalent to `(*sp)++` because postfix `++` operator has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than unary `*` operator.

Comment: I see. And `++*sp` is equivalent to `++(*sp)`, why? the prefix `++` is higher than `*` indeed.

Comment: If you expect the prefix `++` operator to increment its right-hand side operator, what do you expect to get incremented, if not the result of the `*` operator, because that's the only thing that exists on its right-hand side? When  you have two operators on the opposite sides of an expression, their relative priorities now become important. When both operators are on the same side of an expression, there aren't that many differences of opinion, that require the involvement of operator priorities to resolve.